# Получение расчитанных данных из phpexcel

Tags: php, phpexcel

Ребята, нужна ваша помощь.

Есть excel, который заполняю через PHPExcel. 
Сам excel рассчитывает данные по формулам.
Есть к примеру формула =ЕСЛИ(E8="";"";((СЕГОДНЯ()+ДАТА(;D61+1;))-E8)/365,25)

Пытаюсь получить рассчитанное значение

```
require_once ('Classes/PHPExcel/IOFactory.php');
$Excel1 = PHPExcel_IOFactory::load('simple.xlsx');
$Excel1->setActiveSheetIndex(0);
$aSheet = $Excel1->getActiveSheet();

$AgeRepayment = $Excel1->getActiveSheet()->getCell('E9')->getCalculatedValue();

echo $AgeRepayment;
```

Но в ответ получаю #Value
А getOldCalculatedValue() возвращает 0.

Помогите, пожалуйста.

Comment: Понимаю, что проблема с датами, но пока никак не получается решить.

Comment: обратите внимание на этот пост про режим дебага https://stackoverflow.com/a/16708771/1216425

Comment: Да, уже пробовал - получил отчет Formula Value Expected Value is UNKNOWN, но то теперь делать с этим непонятно.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как с датами решить вопрос пока не совсем понял - пришлось написать функцией. 
А с другими параметрами решить получилось - ошибка появляется тогда, когда ячейки, используемые в функциях в excel содержат не те значения, например, если у Вас в численной ячейке содержится буква, или как в моём случае "%".
Во первых обработал все значения подобные через трим

```
$LiqP1 = trim($LiqP, '%');
```

А во-вторых до обработки файла(например пока данные не пришли) - у Вас некоторые поля могут выдавать что-то типа #DIV/0! или #N/A 
эти поля так же обработал путём

```
if($InternalScoreS == '#DIV/0!'){
    $InternalScoreS = 0;
}
```

и

```
if($DeviationCode1 == '#N/A'){
    $DeviationCode1 = "";
}
```

И уже нормально, через обычный getCalculatedValue() уже получаем все данные. 
Надеюсь кому-то поможет.